# Graph drawing algorithm

Tags: c, graph, graph-drawing

I have an undirected graph on matris by vertex adjacency relations like that;

```
    /*    a  b  c  d
     * a -1  0  1  1
     * b  0 -1  1  1
     * c  1  1 -1  1
     * d  1  1  1 -1 
     *
     */

    int G[4][4] = {{-1, 0, 1, 1},
                   { 0,-1, 1, 1},
                   { 1, 1,-1, 1},
                   { 1, 1, 1,-1}};
```

I want to draw this graph on cordinate system. What's the algorithm that gives each vertex position (x,y) by any method(force-directed, spring vs)? I just ask the pseudocode, not any library or software to draw.
Thanks.

Comment: Are there any other requirements?  How about just putting them in a circle?

Comment: @cato: No, thanks. I'm just interesting about positions. I'm using allegro5 to draw circle or line.

Comment: I mean, have the positions be points around a circle.  For example, if there are four vertices, you would have one at the top, left, bottom, and right.

Comment: The positions and whole graph shape are not necessary. By the way, there are more than 100 vertices.

Comment: Why every questions about graph drawing are unanswered or unsolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the well-decribed algorithm with as3. I solved the my problem. Thanks. http://blog.ivank.net/force-based-graph-drawing-in-as3.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a circle graph layout modified from the [prefuse](http://prefuse.org) library:

```
void layoutPoints(int rows, int cols, Point **coordinates, Rectangle maxSize)
{
    int nn = rows * cols;
    int width = maxSize.width;
    int height = maxSize.height;
    int centerX = maxSize.x + (width / 2);
    int centerX = maxSize.y + (width / 2);

    int radius = 0.45 * (height < width ? height : width);

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
             double angle = (2 * M_PI * i) / nn;
             double x = cos(angle) * radius + centerX;
             double y = sin(angle) * radius + centerY;
             coordinates[i][j].x = round(x);
             coordinates[i][j].y = round(y);
        }
    }
}
```

You could change this to use floats or doubles if you needed to as well.

Comment: Can you explain what are rows, cols, coordinates, maxSize?

Comment: @miqbal rows: Number of rows in the graph. cols: number of columns in the graph. coordinates: a 2D array of points, the size of rows x cols, to put the end coordinates in. maxSize: the max size of the boundaries of the graph (x, y, width, height).